Packer - accessing public key of EC2 instance in user_data
I want to create a Windows AMI using Packer, which I'll be able to connect using SSH, authenticating using a private key (not a password).
So, I've found this SO answer that explains how to do it. Shortly, you access the user profile of the machine and pull the public key that's associated with the EC2 instance. You then add this public key to the authorized_keys, and that way you can authenticate using the corresponding private key.
So I've tried adding the given code snippet (after verifying that it works outside the context of packer) in the user_data field in my Packer template. I've created the AMI using Packer, and then spawned an instance of this AMI, associating the instance with an existing key pair. Then, I've tried to connect using the private key - without success.
Apparently, the public key that existed in the instance wasn't the one I've expected - it wasn't the one that I've associated with the EC2 instance. Rather, it was a a public key that the comment in the end was: packer_665c35ea-da1a-6ed1-d422-57176f2abda6
I feel that I don't quite understand when exactly the provided user_data run exactly - does it run on the first time I spawn a new instance out of the AMI (in which case it should run with my provided key pair), or is it run as part of the image creation by packer (in which case, my key is still not in the game).
Can someone explain?!

I would personally just use the winrm transport protocol for this as it would be very quick and easy with Packer, but do you have a requirement to use ssh instead? You could always try using the ssh parameters in the communicator and observe the results.
